# Could not start SASL when connect hive with LDAP

Tags: ldap, sasl, impyla

1. when connecting to a hive-server without authenticate, it works fine, like this:

   conn = connect(host='host.without.authenticate.', port=xxx, database=xxx, auth_mechanism='PLAIN')
2. when connecting to a hive-server with ldap authenticate as follow, occurs the sasl error.

> Could not start SASL: Error in sasl_client_start (-4) SASL(-4)

I have installed `saal` and `thrift-sasl`, and can login in hive by shell:

```
conn = connect(host='host.with.ldap.authenticate.', port=xxx, database=xxx, auth_mechanism='LDAP', user=xxx, password=xxx)
```

Configuration: ubuntu 14, python2.7
I have visit the issue https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/issues/149 but no applicable methods
I don't know what's wrong, and appreciate for your answers